# Comparing two n×m matrices

Tags: c#, csv, complexity, edit-distance

I have to do a pairwise compare of a couple of text files. They have the following format:

```
id_1|errorcode_1|m|data_1_1|data_1_2|...|data_1_m
id_2|errorcode_2|m|data_2_1|data_2_2|...|data_2_m
  .
  .
  .
id_n|errorcode_n|m|data_n_1|data_n_2|...|data_n_m
```

The columns are ordered, but the rows can be in an arbitrary order. And there are always a couple of data-fields that have to be ignored.

This is my method that I call twice (switching the target and source array). It takes around 20 minutes to execute with two files where n = 16000 and m = 100.

```
private static string[] GetDifferences( IEnumerable<string> source  
                                      , IEnumerable<string> target  
                                      , IEnumerable<int> ignoredIndices)
{
    var uniqueInSource = new List<string>();

    foreach (var sourceLine in source)
    {
        var found = false;
        var sourceSplit = sourceLine.Split('|').ToList();

        // filter out malformed lines
        if (sourceSplit.Count > 2 && !int.TryParse(sourceSplit[2], out _))
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var index in ignoredIndices)
        {
            sourceSplit.RemoveAt(index + 3);
        }

        foreach (var targetLine in source)
        {
            var targetSplit = targetLine.Split('|').ToList();

            if (targetSplit.Count > 2 && !int.TryParse(targetSplit[2], out _))
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var index in ignoredIndices)
            {
                targetSplit.RemoveAt(index + 3);
            }

            if (targetSplit.SequenceEqual(sourceSplit))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            uniqueInSource.Add(string.Join("|", sourceLine));
        }
    }

    return uniqueInSource.ToArray();
}
```

I feel that my approach might be too naive since I think it's somewhere around O(m*n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: I think it is O(m*n).  Split should be a method rater than repeat code.  Consider removing the rows when you get a match.

Comment: Why RemoveAt(index + 3)?  Why 3?

Comment: @Paparazzi the list of fields does not contain the first three (id, error and no of results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is currently doing three things at a time and repeating the same logic multiple times:

- parsing logs-1 (parsing a line)
- parsing logs-2 (parsing a line again with the exact same code)
- comparing both logs

It would be much easier to optimize and use it if you refactored it into  specialized structures/methods.

---

You put the first two cases into the static factory method `Parse`. It'll encapsulate the parsing part so you have implemented it only once.

Then you need to encapsulate the equality. You do this by implementing the `IEquatable<LogLine>` interface. You should do this very carefuly because both the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods are important for the performance.

This new class can now be very easily tested for: equality, parsing and performance.

```
public class LogLine : IEquatable<LogLine>
{
    public string Errorcode { get; set; }

    public string[] Data { get; set; }

    // add other properties...

    public static LogLine Parse(string log, IEnumerable<int> ignoreColumns)
    {
        // implement parsing
    }

    public bool Equals(LogLine other)
    {
        // implement log equality
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj as LogLine);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // implement log hash-code
    }
}
```

And that's it because you now have a very LINQ-friendly class that you can use like this where you can parse all lines with a simple `Select`:

```
// dummies
var logs1 = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
var logs2 = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
var ignoreColumns = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

var logLines1 = logs1.Select(l => LogLine.Parse(l, ignoreColumns));
var logLines2 = logs2.Select(l => LogLine.Parse(l, ignoreColumns));
```

And you can compare them however you like with `Except` or `Intersect` or use `GroupBy` or `Distinct` or whatever you want. If you use more then a single extension should call `.ToList()` after each parsing so that you don't parse them multiple times.